# db.SaveChanges() taking long time to save data into DB

Tags: database, entity-framework, insert, entity-framework-6, savechanges

So I am using db.SaveChanges() to save 2500 records into DB. It is taking > 1 min to insert all the records. Then I saw a post here recommending bulkinsert from ZEntityFramework but the problem is you can only use trial version for 1 month and we cant do that in Production server unless you buy. I know SQLBulkCopy is an option in ADO but I dont want to switch from EF. I tried things like db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; but still it takes around a minute to insert data. Is there any option in EF to save data faster? Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

EF Core added batching support.  And there are free alternatives to get SqlBulkCopy working with EF collections.

Here's one I wrote a long time ago, which has found it's way into lots of different projects.  I gave it a new home at GitHub

https://github.com/dbrownems/ObjectDataReader/blob/main/ObjectDataReader.cs

It's very fast and simple, and you simply add the .cs file to your project, import the namespace, and you can convert your Entity collections to a DataReader or DataTable for use with SqlBulkCopy or similar.

Comment: Thanks David. Will look into it.